# vue-cliでaxiosを使う

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

vue-cliでaxiosを使いapiで値を取得したいのですが、vueファイルひとつに全てを書きたいです。

```
axios.get('api-url').then(response => ( 変数A = response))
```

(catchは省略してます)
変数Aを同ファイルの

```
<template><div>{変数A}</div></template>
```

実現するには、どのように記述をすればよろしいですか？

Comment: APIサーバーをクッションにしたら解決しました。